# Automysqlbackup fix error "Skipping the data of table mysql.event. Specify the --events option explicitly"

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I need to fix the `mysqldump` warning **"-- Warning: Skipping the data of table mysql.event. Specify the --events option explicitly."**.

I [found](http://www.linuxbrigade.com/warning-skipping-data-table-mysql-event/) that its because of not specifying whether or not to add events table in mysqldump.

I need to know how to specify the  events option inside [automysqlbackup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/automysqlbackup.8.html) config file.

Comment: you may add another parameter of --eventes and then can use accordingly

Comment: @NawazSohail Sorry. I didn't catch that. Can you please show an example.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the Server Fault question [How to avoid mysqldump warning “Skipping the data of table mysql.event”](https://serverfault.com/q/544237):

> User [Shane on a bike](https://serverfault.com/users/176993/shane-on-a-bike) wrote:
>
> > Modify or Create your ~/.my.cnf and create a mysqldump section by adding the following
> >
> > ```
> > [mysqldump]
> > events
> > ignore-table = mysql.events
> > ```